# How to change values of array in given interval

Tags: c++, arrays, intervals

In c++.
I have array initialized to value 1 with  a size of N. I need to change some values of it(to 0).Indexes that need to be changed to 0 are in form of interval(first,last). 
Beging of a c++ code:

```
int N,l,n;       //l is first and n is last
scanf( "%d", &l );
scanf( "%d", &n );
for(int i =0;i<N;++i){
    N[I] = 1;
}
```

So I need to change value of arr in interval (l,n). How can I do so?

**EDIT:**
**EXAMPLE:**

```
Int arr[10]  = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}             
Int l =2, n=3               
// something                                             
arr[10] ={1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

I think that best answer is this:

```
while(l<=n){
    N[l] = 0;
    ++l;
}
```

Comment: What is `N`? Arrays in C++ need to be defined to be a constant size at compile time. Maybe you're looking for a `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: ```N``` should be size of array.

Comment: Please post example array values before and after the change you want to make. I don't understand what "in form of interval" means. What does `l` and `n` represent exactly? What interval, in what units? What is `interval(l, n)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int arr[N] = { 1 };
```

only sets the first element to 1, all other elements are set to 0.

To set elements between `l` and `n` you can use a loop

```
int i;
for (i = l; i <= n; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
}
```

I recommend using a `std::vector<int>` instead of an array

```
std::vector<int> arr(N, 1);
```

This set all elements inside `arr` to 1.

For `l` to `n`, you can either use the loop above or:

```
std::fill(arr.begin() + l, arr.begin() + n + 1, 0);
```

Note: this assumes that `0 <= l <= n < N`.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I change them in 2nd step for interval.Maybe with wile loop, if ```n>l```, untill ```n==l```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `for` loop from above sets the elements between `l` and `n` to the value 12. You don't need a `while` loop and shouldn't use one. The `for` loop is much more expressive.

Comment: I mean while loop which will set arr[n],arr[n+1.....,arr[n+x ==l]

Comment: I perfectly agree with what @phlipsy said: A for loop is much more expressive than a while loop. I only use a while loop, if I can not determine how many iterations the loop will perform a priori (e.g. reducing a residuum in numerical calculations).